# Issue boost::python::numpy: Exception thrown if "boost::numpy::initialize "

Tags: python, numpy, exception, boost

If I wish to use boost::numpy, I need to call boost::python::numpy::initialize(), but then I get a boost::python::throw_error_already_set exception whenever I boost::python::extract an element of a boost::python::list.

I wrote a small example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
boost::python::list stdvector2pylist(const std::vector<T> &stdvector) {
    boost::python::list pylist;
    for (auto i_T : stdvector ) {
        pylist.append(i_T);
    }
    return pylist;
}

template< typename T >
std::vector< T > pylist2stdvector( const boost::python::list& pyList) {
    auto stdVector = std::vector<T>(len(pyList));
    for (unsigned i_T = 0; i_T < len(pyList); ++i_T) {
        stdVector[i_T] = boost::python::extract<T>(pyList[i_T]);
    }
    return stdVector;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::numpy::initialize();

    std::vector<std::string> words{"1", "2", "3"};
    boost::python::list piwords = stdvector2pylist(words);
    std::vector<std::string> reWords = pylist2stdvector<std::string>(piwords);
}
```

If I comment boost::python::numpy::initialize(); it just works fine.
If the list is send from a Python script, it works.

I'm linking with boost 1.65 and Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Do you actually *have* NumPy installed?

Comment: Yes, numpy is installed. It works if I call an exposed c++ method from a python script, but it throws an exception if I call the same method from a "c++ main".